# Can't get JQuery UI Dialog to do what I want

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I just want a popup window showing a few lines of text. I have this link

```
<a href="" onclick=".dialog('open')">Help</a>
```

and this javascript in my header

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('This dialog will show every time!')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Basic Dialog'
        });

          $('#helpModal').click(function () {
              $dialog.dialog('open');
              // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
              return false;
          });
      });
  </script>
</asp:Content>
```

I keep changing the code to match what I want but I can't get it.
I just want a popup window with some text and have it be gray and focused...with a "Okay" button at the bottom to close the modal window.

I don't think I should be having this much trouble...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your href:

```
<a href="" id="helpModal" >Help</a>
```

in order to the $('#helpModal').click function launch

Fidle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wvQJR/)

If you want to use the onclick in the link .dialog() isn't a valid call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //outside document ready
  function click_link()    {
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('This dialog will show every time!')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Basic Dialog'
        });

        $dialog.dialog('open');
              // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
              return false;
 }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="click_link();" >Help2</a>
```

Fidle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wvQJR/2/)

Comment: Hah, thank you! I mixed up different thing I was trying to do.